# Java - Inner loop is looping, outter loop is not

Tags: java, nested-loops

I have to write a simple program to see how nested loops work. The issue I am having is that my outer loop is not looping. The inner loop works fine, just not the outer.

```
currentRow = 1;
currentColumn = 1;
numRows = 2;
numColumns = 3;

while(currentRow <= numRows){
   currentColumnLetter = 'A';
   while(currentColumn <= numColumns){
      System.out.print("" + currentRow + currentColumnLetter + " ");
      currentColumn++;
      currentColumnLetter++;
   }
   currentRow++;
}
```

Expected results: 1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C

Results I get: 1A 1B 1C

Comment: You're not resetting the value of `currentColumn` at the beginning of the outer loop.

Comment: actually outer loop should be looping normally but inner is only looping the first time... since `currentColumn` is greater that `numColumns` after first iteration of outer loop - adviced to use `for` loops

Comment: moving the initialization of currentColumn into the inside the first loop worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop is an important construct for checking a boolean condition on each loop.  But the for construct is more suited to your use case.  It would have reminded you to reset/increment your loop counter.

```
    int numRows = 2;
    int numColumns = 3;
    char currentColumnLetter;
    for (int currentRow = 1; currentRow <= numRows; currentRow++) {
        currentColumnLetter = 'A';
        for (int currentColumn = 1; currentColumn <= numColumns; currentColumn++) {
            System.out.print("" + currentRow + currentColumnLetter + " ");
            currentColumnLetter++;
        }
    }
```

An example of a while loop use case is when processing iterators.

```
while (myIterator.hasNext()) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to **Reset** the `currentColunm` because you have a condition that if `currentColumn` is lower or equal to some number, it will print.. otherwise it wont..

Thats the problem.. `currentColumn` is going over that condition you have there so **all you need to do** is this ->

```
currentRow = 1;
currentColumn = 1;
numRows = 2;
numColumns = 3;

while(currentRow <= numRows){
   currentColumnLetter = 'A';
   while(currentColumn <= numColumns){
      System.out.print("" + currentRow + currentColumnLetter + " ");
      currentColumn++;
      currentColumnLetter++;
   }
   currentColumn = 1; //This was the part missing
   currentRow++;
}
```